# What is the better way to group data in QT?

Tags: c++, qt

In a QT project I'm working there is a `for loop` in which data is obtained. I need to group the `items` using the `type`. In order to group the items by type the output of my function will be the following QMap `QMap<QString, QList<QString>> groupedItems;`

This is just an example of the input data. In a real situation the types and the amount of items changes every time.

```
QMap<QString, QString> myMap;
myMap.insert("item A", "Type A");
myMap.insert("item B", "Type A");
myMap.insert("item C", "Type D");
myMap.insert("item D", "Type C");
myMap.insert("item E", "Type B");
myMap.insert("item F", "Type A");
myMap.insert("item G", "Type B");
myMap.insert("item H", "Type D");
```

This is my proposal to group the data by type:

```
QStringList types =  myMap.values();
types.removeDuplicates();

QMap<QString, QList<QString>> groupedItems;
for (const auto &type :types) {
    QStringList itemsList;
    for (const auto &key :myMap.keys()) {
        if(myMap[key] == type){
            itemsList.push_back(key);
        }
    }
    groupedItems.insert(type, itemsList);
}

for (const auto &key : groupedItems.keys()) {
    qDebug() << "Type= " << key << " items= " <<groupedItems[key] ;
}
```

output:

```
Type=  "Type A"  items=  ("item A", "item B", "item F")
Type=  "Type B"  items=  ("item E", "item G")
Type=  "Type C"  items=  ("item D")
Type=  "Type D"  items=  ("item C", "item H")
```

The output is the desired. This works, but I think this is not the best way to do this. there is another way (and more efficient) to get the same result without nested for-loops?.

I think QT might already have a powerful way to group data from a QMap.

Thanks

Comment: What's the purpose of nested loops? Why not just a single loop over items, adding them directly to right group?

Comment: @hyde But the size of  `QStringList types` and `myMap` are different. Can you explain your suggestion?

Comment: `groupedList[group].push_back(item)`. If duplicate items are a problem, use `QSet<QString>` instead of a `QStringList`.

Answer (score 1):

How about just:

```
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <vector>

using std::string, std::unordered_map, std::vector;

auto invert(unordered_map<string, string> const& map) {
    unordered_map<string, vector<string>> inverted;
    for (auto const& [key, value] : map) {
        inverted[value].push_back(key);
    }

    return inverted;
}

int main() {
    unordered_map<string, string> map{
        {"item A", "Type A"}, {"item B", "Type A"}, {"item C", "Type D"},
        {"item D", "Type C"}, {"item E", "Type B"}, {"item F", "Type A"},
        {"item G", "Type B"}, {"item H", "Type D"}};

    auto const inverted = invert(map);
}
```

Comment: Sorry if my explanation was not clear. The point is that I have input data and I don't know what the types will be. In the example, I provide some data but the fact is that I can have more types and many elements. The above was just an example.

Comment: How are you getting that data? You're going to have to provide some more context for us to work here.

Comment: In the example I provide, I insert manually keys and values to `myMap`. In the original code the data is inserted in `myMap` in a for loop requesting data to the backend. So, I think it will be not necessary to show the way to get the data, `myMap`  is the starter point and the data could change every time. The main idea is to group the data of `myMap` by type.

Comment: @BadRobot I've updated the sample. See if this helps. Just replace standard types with Qt ones and it should work fine.